# Can anybody explain this Beer-Lambert's law condition for it to be valid?

Tags: optics, definition, laser, spectroscopy, absorption

"The incident radiation should preferably be monochromatic, or have at least a width that is narrower than that of the attenuating transition. Otherwise a spectrometer as detector for the power is needed instead of a photodiode which cannot discriminate between wavelengths."

Why is it invalid if the incident radiation is wider than the attentuation transition?

Comment: The situation is not quite as bad as that quote implies. See my question and answer here: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/117178/79678.